# How insert 1M models in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a file with 1 million lines. I read and insert these line to mssql. The  reading operation takes about a second, but insertion does not work very well here (Time: 00: 03: 36.1424842).

```cs
public async Task<int> InsertAsync(List<Model> models)
{
    var _connectionString =
        "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
    var result = 0;
    try
    {
        using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
        {
            sqlBulk.BatchSize = 10000;
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Counterparty";
            var dt = DataTableHelpers.ListToDataTable(models);
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Debug($"{e.Message} >>> {e.StackTrace}");
    }
    return result;
}
```

My models:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

and file lines:

```
    TestIsert703,Comment694,Adress694,816,1
    TestIsert704,Comment695,Adress695,817,1
```

I tried changing sqlBulk.BatchSize but it does not work for me. How can I insert with good performance. Can I somehow use parallel.for? The load on the laptop is the minimum RAM 1GB, and the processes are generally silent.

Comment: In my experience, doing this inside one single transaction speeds things up quite a bit (although I do not know why, or whether this is true for all scenarios)

Comment: Do you have to do it in C#? You could use SSIS

Comment: I'd say that's because you can keep the connection open rather than having to re-open it over and over again.

Comment: I bet a lot of the time is just in the `ListToDataTable()` method. You say CPU and RAM use are low, so you might do a lot better use some async features to take more advantage of that hardware.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn can you explain or show how would you do it

Answer (score 0):

Are you complaining about inserting a million records in three and a half minutes? You're getting more than 4,500 records per second!

If you really need to speed this up, I see the CPU and RAM use are low, and I bet at least some of the of the time is just in the `ListToDataTable()` method. You might reduce the time by splitting up this part of the work to take more advantage of the hardware.

On the SQL Server side, you can improve this job by switching from FULL to SIMPLE (or even BULK) logged mode, but that's not something I'd want to do all the time. I also see this is a local db. Does SQL Server has access to enough RAM on the system? That can make a *huge* difference.

Comment: Elapsed time of converting models into a datableTime: 00:00:02.2578097. more than 4 gig available for RAM